# How to Encrypt QueryString from IIS

Tags: iis, encryption

Hello everyone,
                          I'm looking for a way to encrypt Query String in my ASP.Net Application. I Search on Internet and found that we can do this by first encrypting them, then send it and than decrypt it. But with this solution will take much time as I will have to go to every page and find where Im using Request.QueryString.

Now I'm thinking cant this be done from IIS, so that I don't have to change my code ?

I hope someone will help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Just use HTTPS, the query string and in fact everything except the host portion of the URL is encrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As already pointed out in the comment,you can just run using https and
>   no one can snoop your query string values. But if you do not want the
>   users to see the query string values, You can write a custom
>   HTTPModule in IIS  .

There is already a module written for this,please check out [httpmodule-for-query-string-encryption](https://madskristensen.net/post/httpmodule-for-query-string-encryption)

Comment: I tried to run my application using https protocol but still i can see query string parameters as plain text

Comment: as i was saying users can see it whether you run it on https or http.But when the data is transmitted over the wire ,it will all be encrypted.Even if someone takes a network trace,you cannot see any value. if you want the users not see the value,you have to use the httpmodule

Comment: Thanks everyone for their replies, I used the module mentioned above and it worked well.